# Advantage of LDAP over RDBMS?

Tags: ldap, rdbms

I have an application with a backend as database.

The application is sort of PUB-SUB model where users post changes to the application and other peers subscribe to those changes. These changes may happen very frequently or periodically and all the changes have to be written to database.

Now, I am being asked to find the possibility of replacing this RDBMS with LDAP. Probably they want unified DB for all applications but anyways I have to find the advantage/disadvantages of both approaches.

I cannot directly compare RDBMS a with LDAP as I have almost no idea of LDAP though I tried to get some.

I understand that LDAP is designed for directory access and is optimized for Read access, so it is write once and read many. I have read that frequent writes will reduce the performance of LDAP server as each write will result a trigger to indexing process.

Just to give a scenario in regards with indexing in LDAP, my table will have few columns say 2 viz. Name and Desc. Now in LDAP I suppose this would become two attributes as Name and Desc. In my scenario it's Desc which will be frequently updated. I assume Name will be indexed so even if Desc is changing frequently it won't trigger indexing process.

I point is worth mentioning that the database will be hosted on some cloud platform.

I tried to find out the differences but nothing conclusive I could find out.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. You may as well compare the advantages of apples over oranges. A RESTful service assumes HTTP and therefore the Internet. You wouldn't expose an LDAP server to the Internet. And an LDAP server isn't suitable for PUB/SUB services in the slightest. It sounds like nobody knows anything about LDAP but they're thinking of using it anyway. Why?

Comment: @EJP: "They're thinking of using it anyway. Why?" -- I don't know :). 
LDAP server will not be directly exposed on the internet, the cloud is a private cloud and the front end application is only one to interact with the DB.
And even if LDAP is not suitable for such scenarios I need some strong concrete statements to back my words. I would appreciate if you can provide me some comments or resources to understand why it is not suitable.

Comment: In other words you've mis-stated your question. You want to *retain* the REST interface and change the *database* from, presumably, an RDBMS to LDAP, for some unstated reason, apparently in the mistaken belief that it will offer some unstated improvement. I still cannot see the point. I suggest *you* ask why. Show 'them' this thread. I believe you will find there is an invalid assumption underlying all this.

Comment: Re the scenario you mention, you *can't* just have an LDAP table with only Name and Desc: LDAP schemas are pre-configured, unless you also want to take the extra learning step of defining your own LDAP schemas, which is non-trivial in the extreme. LDAP is used for authorization and authentication. It isn't a general-purpose database.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you there @EJP but you can use LDAP like a "general purpose database" but you will then have to know what you do and it will not be trivial as you already stated. To reduce LDAP to authorization and authentication is in my opinion unfair ;-)

Comment: @heiglandreas How? You are constrained by the installed schemas, unless you write your own; by the available attribute syntax rules, which are built into the implementation, and cannot be changed or supplemented by the user; and by the non-availability of standard 'general purpose database' features such as joins, grouping, SQL functions, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: that's what I meant by "like". You have to know what you do, know its limitations, work around shortcommings and so on. You can't use LDAP AS replacement of a DB but - depending on your requirements - As storage backend. With the limitations you memtioned. It can be much more than simple Authentication backend. It's not an SQL backend but it has features of a NoSQL backend.

Comment: @heiglandreas You're welcome to clarify and expand on the statement in my comment that LDAP isn't a general purpose database, but you aren't contradicting me at all, you are agreeing with me.

Comment: I just wanted to state that LDAP can be MORE than plain authentication and authorization. That was all 

Comment: Nice discussion here.
@EJP: We do not want to retain REST interfaces, it is like forget REST only LDAP. Name and desc was just for giving example. What schemas to use is a different problem altogether which will be looked if we decide to go with LDAP and as **heighlandreas** said that yes we can use it like a general purpose db(this is what I found reading about LDAP.)
And if I summarise my question it will be- 1. Do we get any performance improvement at DB side if we replace relational DB with LDAP in this scenario. 2. If yes then we can think of wrapping it with REST or using just like that.

Comment: The performance improvement depends largely on what queries you are going to do. As soon as you do a lot of write operations LDAP might be the wrong decission. Other storage engines might be better there. It also depends on what the data is structured like. I think to get a really satisfyimg anseer you would have to test different setups with your data. Take also NoSQL DBs into comsideration like SOLR, Redis, MongoDB etc. Depends a lot on the type of data.

Comment: @heiglandreas thanks. But I have a doubt on write operations which I have asked in the question above. In the same context I want to ask the meaning of write, is it just insert or both update and insert. As I said that updates will be on non indexed attribute so as per my understanding on indexing this will not affect the performance. And the data- it is going to update very frequently. I'll really appreciate if you can please make things clear for me.

Comment: @heiglandreas I didn't say otherwise. I said it is used for that, and it is. You seem to be over-reacting here. We're on the same side.

Comment: @user327959 Then the question still doesn't make sense. You want to forget REST so you no longer have a Web interface, and you don't want to expose LDAP over the Internet, so there is a major missing piece of the puzzle, and the complete lack of a plausible motivation for this design remains.  You're now talking about a performance improvement, but why do you think there will be one? and why haven't you considered the major implementation problems described here? It's futile continuing the discussion if you just keep doing this.

Comment: @EJP I do not have great idea of LDAP but what I understand is that it is basically used for directory lookup within an enterprise. The db is located on some network location within the enterprise and some applications use LDAP protocol to access it, now in my case only thing changing is the db is hosted on cloud and that will be a private cloud so it is similar to a db within the enterprise. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. If I am correct then why do I need any wrapper over it? Although I can have it I am not denying that.

Comment: @EJP - Lets agree on that we agree ;-) -

Comment: @user327959 - There are many more things you have to take into account than simply "speed on writing" (creating and updating are both write operations) - Do you have a single or multiple LDAP-Servers? Are they setup as MultiMaster or Master-Slave environment? Are they distributed accros the world? All those factors can have a severe influence on "speed" both for writing and for reading. So as I said before, it depends largely on what you are doing. And most of the time the bottleneck is NOT the data-backend - be it relational Database or LDAP.

Comment: @user3275095 So you're already using LDAP and just moving it into the cloud? Really this continues to be most unclear. You're retaining/removing/forgetting REST; you're changing from REST to LDAP/from a database to LDAP/you're only moving an existing LDAP into the cloud; ...

Comment: @EJP As of now we do not have LDAP, its a relational DB on the cloud exposed using REST interfaces. Guys I understand that you are trying to help and I thank you for that but it is increasingly becoming complicated here. What I am asking here now is simple - for a given scenario will LDAP perform better/worse than a relational DB? I think this would have been a better question instead of putting up the whole background.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP is a protocol, REST is a service based on the HTTP (protocol). So when the LDAP server shall not be exposed to the internet, how do you want to get the data from it? As LDAP is the protocol you would need direct access to the LDAP-server. Its like a database server that you would not expose directly to the internet. You would build an interface to encapsulate it. and that might as well be a REST interface.

I'd try to get the point actos that one is the transfer protocol and a storage backend and the ither is the public interface to its data. It's a bit like why is mysql better than a webinterface. You'd never make the mysql-server publicly available but encapsulate its protocol into an application.

REST is an interface. It doesn't matter how you orgsnize your data behind that interface. When you decide that you want to organize it differently you can do so without the consumer of your API noticing any change. And you can provide different versions of your API depending on improvements of your service.

LDAP on the other hand is an implementation. You can't change the way your data is handled without the consumer noticing it. So there's no way to rearrange your backend without affecting the consumer.

With REST you can therefore change the backend from MySQL to PostgreSQL even to LDAP without notice which you won't be able with LDAP.

Hope that helps

Comment: I understand the basic difference as you told. But as I mentioned earlier LDAP is not directly exposed to the clients. Clients will access the application and the app will itself access the backend DB using LDAP or REST so the client is already unaware of this. 
I have one doubt as I read about LDAP, it is said that it is an internet protocol to access directories, so in my scenario what difference does the database in cloud makes?

Comment: I understood your questin so that you were asked to replace a RESTful interface with LDAP. That doest make sense as you can't replace an API with a backend as I described. When the question is whether you can replace the bACKEND of your API with LDAP thats a totaly different question which requires a more detailed look but also requires more informations.

Answer (score 0):

***Now that we finally know what you're actually asking,*** which has *nothing to do* with your title, the body of your question, *or* REST, the simple answer is that there is no particular reason to believe that an LDAP server will perform significantly better than an RDBMS in this application, with two riders:

1. it may not even be feasible, due to the schema issue, and
2. if it is feasible it may not be semantically suitable, due to the lack of ACID properties, lack of JOINs, and the other issues mentioned in comments.

I will state that this is one of the worst formulated questions I have seen here for some considerable time, and the difficulty of extracting the actual question was extreme.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I have asked in the question are the points which I have to eventually look for. For example compare the caching at the accessing application side. Here the debate went into what was right and wrong where the servers are etc.. Now again here what you answered is based on some assumptions about the type of data and yes these points are worth considering, but I asked which one will perform better. Just assume I don't need all ACID, JOINs etc. My question was in respect to multiple reads and writes and indexing but sadly debate went somewhere else.

Comment: Now if I found the LDAP a better choice then again I would have to look if accessing it through REST is better or directly using LDAP. Probably, I shouldn't have mentioned the whole scenario rather should have asked two different questions :). And after all the pain you two have gone through I still nowhere. Sorry to my knowledge to LDAP.